# porque no me muestra nada el videoview

Tags: android

Este es el código pero no me muestra nada solo se cierra la app

VideoView video;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    video = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.pantallaVideo);
    video.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    video.setVideoPath("http://192.168.15.214/PruebaConexion/S01E01.mkv");
    video.start();
}
```

El error que me da es el siguiente

> MediaPlayer: setDataSource: IOException!
>   uri=http://192.168.15.214/PruebaConexion/S01E01.mkv

y este otro error

> dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle',
>   referenced from method
>   com.example.erick.reproducirvideo.MainActivity.access$super

PD: tengo el servidor en mi compu y el video es en formato mkv

Answer (score 0):

Debes tomar en cuenta que el formato .mkv es soportado en Android 4.0+, codecs de video H.264 y audio AAC.

https://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Pero en tu caso por el error `IOException` asegura que el url:
http://192.168.15.214/PruebaConexion/S01E01.mkv
pueda ser leido correctamente y exista el archivo.

Comment: el android que tengo en mi celular es el 4.2 y cuando busco en internet por medio de esa url si me reproduce el video